# Modalform closes when openFileDialog returns a result from the second form

Tags: c#, winforms

**Form1** opens **Form2** with Form2.ShowDialog(). Inside **Form2** a file dialog is opened. When the file browser is closed Form2 is also closed (since a DialogResult is fired i guess)

I can't seem to find a solution for this by searching, maybe because i don't know exactly what to search for. So what would be the preferred way of achieving this without **Form2** closing?

Comment: Which event do you use to open the FileDialog()? If you use a button click event, have you checked if your button has its DialogResult property set to something?

Comment: That's not default behavior. What is the code for opening the file dialog in Form2?

Comment: Oh, the DialogResult of the button was set to OK for some reason. Feels so bad now that i've wasted so much time on this.. :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Apparently this was not default behavior as I thought it was. The DialogResult property of the button in form2 did indeed have it's value set to OK, which I wasn't aware of. Setting this to none solved this simple issue. Thanks for the help :)